Fundamental domain for the action on curve complex
Suppose $S$ is a surface and the Mapping Class Group, $Mod(S)$, of $S$, is the group of self-homeomorphisms of $S$, up to isotopy. This group acts on a graph called "curve graph", denote by $\mathcal{C}(S)$. The construction of this graph can be found in "A primer on mapping class groups" by Benson Farb and Dan Margalit.
I was studying the paper by Masur and Minsky: Geometry of the complex of curves I: Hyperbolicity, where they proved that curve graph is hyperbolic in the sense of Gromov. In the introduction of the paper they have written and I quote: "it is plain that $Mod(S)$ acts isometrically on $\mathcal{C}(S)$, with compact quotient."
I was finding difficulty to understand that why there will be compact quotient, and what is the fundamental domain.
Thanks in advance.

This follows from the “change of coordinates principle” described in Farb-Margalit’s primer.

the change of coordinate principle says that between two distinct, non-separating curves there is  a homeomorphism sending one to other. does that mean there is only one orbit?

That’s just one example of the change of coordinates principle.  Go back and read that chapter of the primer.

(a good test of your understanding of it is that the cocompactness of the action becomes obvious, though it is a bit annoying to write down a fundamental domain)

A meaningful question would be about cardinality of the simplex set of the curve complex modulo the mapping class group (or, better, the pants complex), generalizing the Catalan numbers. I do not know an answer to this one but it might be in the literature.

@MoisheKohan: You've got to be careful since stabilizers of simplices need not stabilize the simplices pointwise, so the quotient is not a simplicial complex unless you subdivide first to fix this issue.  Probably the more natural question would be to just count the orbits of k-simplices.  I'm sure I've seen a formula for this in the literature somewhere, but I don't know where off the top of my head.

@AndyPutman I asked this question because it was written in that paper by Masur and Minsky: "up to the action of MCG(\Sigma), there are only finite number of distinct non-trivial non-peripheral homotopy classes of simple curves in \Sigma (distingused bt the topological type of their complement)"

@ggt001 the parenthetical actually answers your question ;)

@RyleeLyman yes correct!!! but I also want to know what is a fundamental domain, more specifically what are the finite number of orbit representatives that survives under quotient. The above quote suggests that they should be non-trivial non-peripheral simple curves in \Sigma.

As Andy says, that the action is co-compact follows from the "change of coordinates principle".  Finding a fundamental domain for $S_2$ (the compact, connected, oriented, boundary-less surface of genus two) is a nice exercise.  The problem of finding a fundamental domain for $S_g$ quickly succumbs to "combinatorial explosion".
